# How to print even numbers from a user supplied input

Tags: linux, bash

I have this code here and what its supposed to do it this:

the user enters the Max number. and based on that number entered, I want to display all the even numbers up to that number.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "What is your max number:"

read counter


for number in {0.."$counter"}

if [ (($number % 2 == 0)) ]
then
echo "$number"
fi
```

but it doesn't work. rather I receive this error when I call he script from the terminal:

```
[root@sunshine Desktop]# bash Tester
What is your max number:
9
Tester: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
Tester: line 9: `if [ (($number % 2 == 0)) ]'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the `do` and `done` parts of the `for` loop.
And in any case, you cannot use a variable with the `{a..b}` syntax,
unfortunately.
You need to write as a counting loop instead.
And then you can increment by 2,
which eliminates the check for even numbers:

```
for ((number = 0; number < counter; number += 2)); do
    echo "$number"
done
```

Lastly, I recommend to rename the variables to:

- `counter` -> `max`
- `number` -> `counter`

Putting it all together:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "What is your max number:"    
read max

for ((counter = 0; counter < max; counter += 2)); do
    echo "$counter"
done
```

Comment: The reason why you can't use {0..$var} is because brace expansion is done before parameter expansion, therefore it is not a valid expansion at the time Bash processes it. You can refer to [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler method:

```
seq 0 2 $counter
```

---

Variables *can* be passed to brace expansion, using another invocation of `bash`:

```
bash -c 'printf "%i\n" {0..'$counter'..2}'
```

Or `eval`:

```
eval 'printf "%i\n" {0..'$counter'..2}'
```

Neither of those last two methods is safe, unless it's certain that `$counter` is  a number.